# Setting window root viewcontroller Bad access without stack trace

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

Edit: It seems this was a stupid mistake by me, i got a rotationChanged notification too early, before i could process it. That caused a chain reaction which caused a crash in some obscure location. Let me see how i can close/delete this question...

My app's been working fine for a while, but i decided today to finally implement it 'correctly', that is: Use a view controller instead of manually adding a single view to the UIWindow. This went quite smooth for a while, untill i tried setting window.rootViewController to my view controller.

Somewhere after applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, it crashes with a bad access. There's no useful stacktrace (it crashes in the assembly), and i can't see it getting back into my code anywhere (i placed logs all over the place). Just adding the viewcontroller's view to the main window works fine. This is the part of the code:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ....
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
    // if i uncomment this it crashes:
    // self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window addSubview: viewController.view]; // Commented out if i use the rootViewController

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"Did finish launching");
    return YES;
}
```

I've tried quite some debugging methods (stacktrace does not exist, stepping through the code manually takes forever, logs are not being called before the crash), but i can't find the problem. It crashes in `libobjc.A.dylib'objc_retain:`, and the only other thing in the stacktrace is `objc_storeStrong`. It's not a retain/release problem (at least not directly), since i'm using ARC. The final NSLog is called and it gets out of the didFinishLaunching if i step through manually.

I can get the app working without setting the root view controller, but the whole point of redoing this part was to do everything 'proper' (e.g. rotation has to be done relatively hackish without the root view controller).

so StackOverflow, please tell me you have some ideas! As this is driving me crazy :S

Comment: Have you tried just setting self.window.rootViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]init]?

Comment: Now i did, doesn't work. Thanks for the idea though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was a stupid mistake by me, i got a rotationChanged notification too early, before i could process it. That caused a chain reaction which caused a crash in some obscure location. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: rotationChanged notification? could you elaborate?

Comment: Although this post is over 4 years old, I believe it was this notification: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientationdidchangenotification . In the handler for that event, I tried changing or setting something that was not yet initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this:

```
[self.window addSubview: viewController.view];
```

When you set the view controller as root view controller, it's view already becomes subview of the window.

**EDIT**

However this wouldn't cause any problem.

Maybe the problem isn't in the code. Sometimes my apps crash too, and I get mad. Usually this happens because I drag the project from another folder and xcode finds troubles with permissions, or for some other (to me) unknown reasons.

Try to clean the project with alt+cmd+k .  If that doesn't work you might have problems with permissions. So create another project and copy all the files you wrote to it.

Comment: I comment that one out if i use the rootviewcontroller, sorry for not being clear on that one. Will edit my question.